# how to add a new column to an existing data table in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created the data table for 'order' entity. Now I want to add a new column for that existing table. The new attribute to be added is a boolean value which must be having 'false' by default.
Is there a way to do this?
[image: This is the existing data table. (I have deleted all the data in the table that's why they are staying as null.)]

This is the model. (The attribute which should be added is as I have commented in the code. I don't know whether the way I have done it right or wrong. But it is not working. I added the code but it does not add a column to the data table.)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace E_Pharmacy.Models
{
    public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; }

        //[DefaultValue(false)]
        //public bool Complete { get; set; } //this is the attribute which should be added newly.
        public string Status2 { get; set; }
        public string PharmacyName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string PatientName { get; set; }
        public int PatientAge { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int TeleNo { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        
        public string ImageName{ get; set;}

        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public String ImageSrc { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Pharmacy")]
        public int PharmacyId { get; set; }
        //public Pharmacy Pharmacy { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Can some expert help me in this matter please?

Comment: Example how to [Add a new field to the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/new-field?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) with Code First approach.

Comment: You need to do a migration or use EnsureCreated().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to add [DefaultValue(false)],  just public bool Complete is enough.

First, Add a new Migration:

```
Add-Migration initxxxxx(new name)
```

Then a new migration file will show with these code:

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<bool>(
            name: "Complete2",
            table: "Order",
            type: "bit",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: false);
```

You can see that defaultValue is set by default. But if you want to change defaultValue to  true, you should change **AddColumn** to **AlterColumn** and change the defaultvalue, or the change will not be applied.

Finally use **Update-Database**  and refresh your database to check the result:

[image]